# all ways in which the tetrahedral group $T$ can operate on a set of two elements.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I was asked to describe all ways in which the tetrahedral group $T$ can operate on a set of two elements. After some thinking, I saw that $T$ was isomorphic to $A_{4}$. Is it right to think about all the group homomorphisms from $A_{4}$ to $S_{2}$ for this problem?

I know that if $A_{n}$ n>= 5 will be simple group and if it acts on a set with $m < n$ elements then there will only be the trivial homomorphism. However, I am unsure about how to go about this problem with $A_{4}$ if it is the correct approach.

I know that there is at least the trivial homomorphism, but I am not seeing any more. I know that any nontrivial homomorphism will not be injective since the order of $A_4$ is larger than $S_2$ so there will be no bijective homomorphism and hence no isomorphism between the two groups. Thus, I am only seeing the trivial homomorphism from $A_{4}$ to $S_{2}$. Is this correct? However, I also see that any elements of order 2 in $A_4$ get mapped to the non-identitiy elements in $S_2$. So I am not sure if this is correct. Any help would be much appreciated!

**EDIT: Are these the correct homomorphisms between the 2 groups?**

1.) Trivial homomorphism

2.) homomorphism where non-identity elements of order 2 in $A_4$ get mapped to the non-identity element say $x$ in $S_2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A_4$ contains elements of the forms $()$, $(12)(34)$ and $(123)$. The identity $()$ needs to be mapped to the identity, and the elements of the form $(123)$ are of order $3$ and thus also have to be mapped to the identity. The elements of the form $(12)(34)$ are products of the form $(132)(324)$ and thus also have to be mapped to the identity.

Comment: Thanks! So there only exists a trivial homomorphism is what you are saying?

Comment: @bob: Yes, that's what I'm saying :-)

Comment: @joriki how did you get $(12)(34)$  is of the form $(132)(324)$? Are you acting on the right or left?